# How to redirect to a route from a controller method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have defined a method in my controller, where inputs are first retrieved, and if the email field is present in my database, I would like to return a view. However, if the email field isn't present, I would like to redirect to another route. I would also like to pass in the inputs to that route as well.

To better understand what I mean, my code is as follows for my controller:

```
    public function index(Request $request) {

    $credentials = $request->all();

    if (\App\User::where('email','=',$credentials['email'])->exists()){

        //if they are registered, return VIEW called welcome, with inputs

        return view('welcome', $credentials);

    }
    else{//If the user is not in the database, redirect to '/profile' route,
         //but also send their data

        return redirect('profile', $credentials);

    }
```

And my web.php is as follows:

```
Route::post('/profile', function() {
     $m = Request::only('email'); //I only need the email
     return view('profile', $m);
});
```

However, this logic fails with errors: 'HTTP status code '1' is not defined'. 
Is there anyway to do this properly? (i.e. go from my controller method to another route?)

Comment: return redirect()->route('xxx.xxx');

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `redirect()` method.

```
return redirect()->route('route.name')->with(['email'=> 'abc@xys.com']);
```

Since using `with()` with `redirect()` will add 'email' to the session **(not request)**. Then retrieve the email with:

```
request()->session()->get('email')
//Or
session('email')
```

Comment: This will be passed to the session right? I think this is useful.

Comment: Will this work if I do something like: return redirect()->route('profile)->with(['email'=> $credentials['email']])?

Comment: Yes it will be available on next request(redirected route). there you can get in controller.

Comment: Oh @JithinJose, if you will get it in the next request as "request parameter" then you can discard my edit

Comment: I am not able to receive the email using Request, so do I have to use the session as suggested or is there another way?

Comment: Yes you have to get from session in controller

Answer (score 3):

While @JithinJose question gave the answer, I am adding this as answer for those who consider this in the future, and who does not want to deal with getting things like this in the session:

A not-recommended way to do this is to call the controller directly from this controller method, and pass the variable needed to it:

```
$request->setMethod('GET'); //set the Request method
$request->merge(['email' => $email]); //include the request param
$this->index($request)); //call the function
```

This will be okay if the other controller method exists within the same class, otherwise You just have to get the method you need and reuse it.

The best recommended way **if you want to avoid session** is [Redirect to controller action](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#redirecting-controller-actions) i.e:

```
return redirect()->action(
   'UserController@index', ['email' => $email]
);
```

I hope it is useful :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to define the route to which you want to `redirect()`

```
return redirect()->route('profile')->with('credentials', $credentials);
```

The `with` option flashes data to the session which can be accessed as if passed to the view directly.

More information regarding the `session` and flashing data can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data).

Information regarding flashing data after a redirect can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data).

In your case you could use:

```
return redirect()->route('profile')->with('email', $credentials['email']);
```

In your view you could then use it like:

```
@if(session()->has('email')
    We have the email of the user: {{ session('email') }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your view path like :

```
return view('welcome', compact(credentials));

return redirect()->route('profile')->with('credentials',$credentials);
```

Comment: My first view works perfectly tho? I dont think compact is required.