# How to redirect to a POST route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In my controller, I have a method which should redirect to a `POST` route. I can not make this route a `GET` one either. Is there any solutions?

My controller code looks like:

```
// After a bunch of other if statements, etc
return redirect('newUser')->with('user', $user);
```

Now my route (in web.php) is as follows:

```
Route::post('/newUser', function() {
    $user=session('user');
    dd($user);
    return view('profileNewUser', $user);
});
```

The error which is thrown at me is `MethodNotAllowedHTTPException`.

I know my error is something to do with the `_token`, is there anyway I can allow the token field to get passed on? I tried passing it in with the `with` in my redirect but that doesn't work either.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're returning a view on a `POST` request? That seems silly to me

Comment: Yea I know I could have directly returned the view (instead of the redirect), but I need the url to be 'newUser' and not the user associated with my controller. I don't want anyone to go to /newUser either. Would sessions be better to use?

Comment: You should check this answer.https://stackoverflow.com/a/45441085/5704410

Comment: Unfortunately still no answer to this question...

Answer (score 3):

Try redirect to Named Route.

```
Route::post('/newUser', function() {
    $user=session('user');
    dd($user);
    return view('profileNewUser', $user);
})->name('newusr');
```

Then:

```
return redirect()->route('newusr', ['user'=>$user]);
```

Or, redirect to controller actions.

- See this tutorial about redirects: http://coursesweb.net/laravel/redirects

Comment: Named routes or controller actions routes perfom the same.

Comment: I still get the error: `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the url to be 'newUser' then you can simply make a `GET` route of the same url.

The question as to *Why you would want to return the post request to the same route* is still valid, because it might lead to infinite call of the same route.

One way however, is you can add a logic to check if user is already in session then do otherwise, else this kind of pattern is not really good.

Best way is to separate your page that returns the response of your POST from the one that renders a view.

Like I suggested in the comment: you can simply move this `getUser` route into a controller then use Laravel's Response to action or the other way. [Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45441085/5704410) in case you want to browse.

> PS: my answer is based on my understanding of your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see you can only redirect to a post route by using:

```
return back()->withInput(['postvar1' => 'postval1']);  // L5.5
```

This is used under the circumstance when there is an error in a form request.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the middleware folder and finding the `VerifyCsrfToken` file. aap/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php. Then add the route name you need to exempt from csrf token validation

Answer (score 0):

For those who might come here by chance, @omarjebari was in the right track.

It should be `return redirect()->route('<named>')->withInput(<[array data>]);`