# Laravel Redirect as POST

Tags: laravel, redirect, post

Currently my users must get the visit form given by `Route::get` then fill it in to get back a result view given by `Route::post`. I need to create a shareable link such as `/account/search/vrm/{vrm}` where `{vrm}` is the VRM that is usually filled in on the form page. This VRM then needs to redirected to `Route::post` as post data. This needs to be done by my controller. How can I do this in my controller?

**Routes:**

```
// Shows form view
Route::get('/account/search', 'User\AccountController@getSearch')->name('account.search');
// Shows result view
Route::post('/account/search', 'User\AccountController@runSearch');
// Redirect to /account/search as POST
Route::get('/account/search/vrm/{vrm}', function($vrm) { ???????? });
```

Answer (score 6):

POSTs cannot be redirected.

Your best bet is to have them land on a page that contains a form with `<input type="hidden">` fields and some JavaScript that immediately re-submits it to the desired destination.

Comment: Yes, but the other answer does describe the way to effectively achieve this without HTML.

Comment: @NicholasAlexander The other answer won't change the browser URL to the desired route, though. Depending on specific needs, one or the other answer may be appropriate. I presume you're the downvoter today?

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect to a controller action or call the controller directly, see [the answer here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45441085/5704410)

In summary, setting the request method in the controller, or calling a controller's action.

> Ps: I don't want to repeat the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For those who comes later:
If you are using blade templating engine for the views, you can add '@csrf' blade directive after the form starting tag to prevent this. This is done by laravel to prevent cross site reference attacks. By adding this directive, you can get around this.

Answer (score -4):

```
return redirect()->route('YOUR_ROUTE',['PARAM'=>'VARIABLE'])
```